# Mailing with Node.js. Issue with the host property

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, nodemailer

I know there are many posts like this here, but I couldn't find any information that would solve my issue. So I tried using both [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs).

I have this code:

This is for nodemailer

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.Hotmail.com", // Just Hotmail doesn't work either
        // port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'xxx@outlook.com',
            pass: 'xxx'
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: `${req.body.fullName} ${req.body.email}`, // sender address
        to: 'alexander.ironside@mygeorgian.ca', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Email from SMWDB contact form', // Subject line
        html: `<h4>Name: ${req.body.fullName}</h4>
                <h4>Company: ${req.body.company}</h4>
                <h4>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</h4>
                <p>Message: ${req.body.message}</p>`
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

        // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
        // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
});
```

And this for emailjs

```
var email = require("emailjs");
var server = email.server.connect({
    user: "xxx@outlook.com",
    password: "xxx",
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    tls: {ciphers: "SSLv3"}
});

var message = {
    text: `Test`,
    from: `${req.body.fullName} <${req.body.email}>`,
    to: `Alex <alexander.ironside@mygeorgian.ca>`, // list of receivers
    // cc:      "else <else@your-email.com>",
    subject: 'Email from SMWDB contact form', // Subject line
    attachment:
        [
            {
                data: `
            <h4>Name: ${req.body.fullName}</h4>
            <h4>Company: ${req.body.company}</h4>
            <h4>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</h4>
            <p>Message: ${req.body.message}</p>`
                , alternative: true
            },
        ]
};

// send the message and get a callback with an error or details of the message that was sent
server.send(message, (err, message) => {
    console.log(err || message);
});
```

The problem I think is that as `host` both docs say something like this: `smtp.your-email.com`, meanwhile all code examples say this: `host: "Hotmail"`. What's the correct way?

I don't really care which package I'm using.

I have to use Hotmail/Yahoo and cannot use Gmail (Too many accounts activated with one phone number)

Now to the errors:

`Emailjs` throws this:

`{ Error: bad response on command '
.': 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.` and then there is a lot of numbers and a callback trace.

Nodemailer throws this:

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smtp.Hotmail.com smtp.Hotmail.com:587
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
    code: 'ECONNECTION',
        errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'smtp.Hotmail.com',
    host: 'smtp.Hotmail.com',
    port: 587,
    command: 'CONN' }
```

I used to do this in PHP and have no idea why it's so complicated with Node, but I guess there must be a reason.

Comment: I used nodemailer without any problems - I believe it's problem with smtp server - maybe it require some configuration (google e.g.: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and/or specific hostname/port. The other issue can be - you providing wrong sender ("from").

Comment: Use `smtp.live.com` for hotmail.com or live.com email address. Use `smtp-mail.outlook.com` for outlook.com email address.

Comment: @BrahmaDev This caused nodemailer to throw the same error emailjs threw earlier.

Comment: @MichałZ. This code worked for the test email service provided by nodemailer.

Comment: I think you're trying to send email as someone else. This is not for that. You can only send email as `user: "xxx@outlook.com"` that you specify in the configuration.

Comment: I really believe the credentials are correct. When I break the password it throws an authentication error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a friend to create a Gmail account and it worked right away. If you hit the same problem, don't bother with anything else. Just use Google.

That's the transporter code that worked for me

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxx'
    }
});
```

Comment: The mail issue here is to solve the problem. This cannot be the solution. It's just an alternative. How does changing the provider solve the problem. You are still left with the same issue on hand. :)

Comment: If you know of a solution feel free to share it. Changing the provider resulted in a working code. It might not be perfect but it does the job